# Uploadify: Dynamic FormData does not change

Tags: php, upload, uploadify

Based on the current uploadify documents, it uses formData (weird all google search results, ppl are using scriptData). The problem is I tried to manually change the formData using setting and onUploadStart event as this [uploadify docs](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/formdata/) said. However the folder always stay the same (/webroot/newsletter) when it reaches the server. It should be (/webroot/newsletter/update), I am testing this way, as the value should be dynamic later on. Any clue what went wrong here? There is another question in the [uploadify forum](http://www.uploadify.com/forum/#/discussion/8211/method-settings-not-work/p1) too but no answer so far

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
                            'method':'POST',
                            'formData' : { 'currentDirPath' : '/webroot/newsletter' } ,
                            'swf'      : '/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.swf',
                            'uploader' : '/js/uploadify-v3.1/uploadify.php',
                            'checkExisting' : '/js/uploadify-v3.1/check-exists.php',
                            'onUploadStart' : function(file) {
                                 $("#file_upload").uploadify('settings', 'currentDirPath', "/webroot/newsletter/update");
                            } ,
                            'onUploadSuccess' : function(file, data, response) {
                                alert('The file was saved to: ' + data);
                            } 
                            // Put your options here
                        });
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The documentation is wrong. It should be:

```
 $("#file_upload").uploadify('settings','formData' ,{'currentDirPath': /webroot/newsletter/update});
```

Just in case if someone stumble on this problem. Cheers.

Comment: The documentation is very tedious and erroneous. I was thinking about buying the html5 version, but I don't think I will anymore.

Comment: When I use this in Chrome I get the error `Uncaught Call to SetPostParams failed` - any idea why?